# Building a C++ program on MacOS 11.2.1 doesn't work on 10.12.6

Tags: c++, macos, g++, clang

I have a relatively simple C++ program that I want to run on different machines. I built the program on my Mac which has Big Sur 11.2.1 installed and tried running it on another with an earlier version installed. I get this error:

```
dyld: lazy symbol binding failed: Symbol not found: ____chkstk_darwin
  Referenced from: /Users/************/Desktop/CPUbenClang
  Expected in: /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib

dyld: Symbol not found: ____chkstk_darwin
  Referenced from: /Users/************/Desktop/CPUbenClang
  Expected in: /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib

Abort trap: 6
```

Here are the libraries my program uses:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
```

These are extremely simple, basic libraries. I used clang version 12.0.0 to build the program.

It seems rather unacceptable that this severe lack of compatibility between such close versions of Operating Systems exists, unless I'm doing something wrong here.

Searching for this error online reveals that this is a common issue, but with a variety of causes. I wouldn't expect it to be an issue given the simplicity of my program.

Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63221290/how-to-resolve-missing-symbol-chkstd-darwin-in-libsystem-b-dylib-osx

Comment: *this severe lack of compatibility between such close versions of Operating Systems* is legendary with Apple. They are famous for releasing versions of their operating systems that totally lack compatibility with the previous version, causing all installed applications to fail. They've done it that way for decades now.

Comment: Is your XCode and the command line tools installed properly? If you ware updating XCode (or macOS) recently, you will need to update the command line tools as well, however this needs to be done manually.